# Can one FCM token be used for multiple devices of same user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am working on implementing Notification System using Firebase Cloud Messaging. I want to know if the FCM token that is used by Firebase to send notifications can be the same for multiple devices of the same user? Is it possible to do so?
For example, we have an user. I want to generate a single token and store it with the user's profile and send notification to the user on that user's each device using the same token. If the user is logged in on web, as well as app, I want to send notification on both devices using the same token.
Is it possible, if yes then please share any link/doc that may be helpful for me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, each device has unique FCM token so you need to store multiple token for user at your server

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Niranj Patel :)

Answer (score 1):

Each device has diffirent FCM token. If you want to send notification to multi devices, you can send by topic

Comment: Topics are something different, I just wanted to know if there is any user specific way irrespective of device.
Thanks for your answer though :)